# Numpy where for 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2 d numpy array.  I need to keep all the rows whose value at a specific column is greater than a certain number.  Right now, I have:

```
f_left = np.where(f_sorted[:,attribute] >= split_point)
```

And it is failing with: `"Index Error: too many indices for array"`

How should I do this?  I can't figure it out from the numpy website, [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html])

Comment: Can you post sample data: This works fine with a simple case where `attribute = 0`, `split_point = 2`, and `f_sorted = np.arange(20).reshape((2, 10))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't even need where.

```
    yy = np.array(range(12)).reshape((4,3))


    yy[yy[:,1] > 2]
```

## Output

```
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = np.array([[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[1,2,3],[8,9,10]])

array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Find the rows where the second element are `>=4`

```
x[np.where(x[:,1] >= 4)]

array([[ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks...I would not have gotten there (new to python last semester)